# How to create a delegate from Expression<Func< , >>? (pass a parameter to the expression)?

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, expression

I have the following filter :

```
Expression<Func<Employee, bool>> fromDateFilterFourDays = z => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(z.FiringDate) >= EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-4));

Expression<Func<Employee, bool>> fromDateFilterSixDays = z => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(z.FiringDate) >= EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-6));
```

How can I make a delegate out of this filter ?

I don't want to create a variable for each given number , i.e. for four days or six days .

Comment: For complicated linq expressions, I usually just create a helper function to simplify the expression.  it looks like in your case you want to return List<Employee> and pass an int parameter indicating the date range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that you want to:

1. Take in two parameters to the delegate, the employee and the number of days.
2. Compile that expression into a delegate.

The first part can be done by adding the days to the parameter list:

```
Expression<Func<Employee, int, bool>> fromDateFilter = (z, n) => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(z.FiringDate) >= EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(n));
```

The second by using the Compile method:

```
var del = fromDateFilter.Compile();
// use it
del(employee, -4);
```

Comment: Note that just like the name suggests, `Compile` compiles the `Expression`. It's a very expensive operation, even relative to reflection. Don't do it too often.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily turn `Expression<Func<...>>` to `Func<...>` by using `Compile` method.

However, keep in mind that the sample expressions you provided will not work, because they are using [Canonical Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/bg-bg/library/bb738626(v=vs.110).aspx) which are just placeholders for mapping the corresponding database SQL functions, and will throw exception if you try to actually evaluate them (which will happen with `Func`).

From the other side, if the question is actually how to parametrize the sample expressions, it could be like this

```
static Expression<Func<Employee, bool>> DateFilter(int currentDateOffset)
{
    return e => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(e.FiringDate) >= DateTime.Today.AddDays(currentDateOffset);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is done by calling the `Invoke()` method:

```
fromDateFilterFourDays.Invoke(employee);
```

Or you can `Compile()` the expression to a func and then call the func:

```
var fromDateFilterFourDaysFunc = fromDateFilterFourDays.Compile();

fromDateFilterFourDaysFunc(employee);
```